# HTML - random whitespace

Tags: html, whitespace, removing-whitespace

I am creating a website in HTML and everything went well until something weird happened to my code. When I place 2 button side by side, [a random horizontal line becomes visible.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jWOhD.png) When I click on the button and hold it, the line becomes [red.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dxB7K.png)
This has nothing to do with css, when I place the link to the css-file in comment, it still occurs.

When I look into the dev tools, there is an element called [whitespace](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kupTR.png) in it, but this is nowhere in my [code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0sviV.png).

When I search on the internet, the only thing that appears is how to add whitespace.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css">
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Zoeken op bedrijf</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <header>
      <nav>
        <a href="/perSecotr.html">
          <button type="button">Zoeken op sector</button>
        </a>
        <a href="#">
          <button type="button">Zoeken op bedrijf</button>
        </a>
      </nav>
    </header>
    <div>
      <h1>Welk bedrijf wilt u zoeken?</h1>
    </div>
    <div>
      <form autocomplete="off">
        <input type="text" placeholder="Naam van het bedrijf..." id="companyname" required />
        <br>
        <button type="button" id="submit"> Zoeken </button>
      </form>
    </div>
  </body>

  <script src="./js/index.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</html>
```

Comment: The whitespace _is_ in your code. You have a line feed followed by several spaces. Developer tools are showing it explicitly because it's relevant for layout.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This happens because you are using `a` tag which in default has a `text-decoration` set to `underline`.

To fix this you need add a css rule

```css
a {
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The `<a>` HTML element (or anchor element) is underlined by default. It is wrong to put a `<button>` inside the `<a>` element. If you are only going to give a **link**, you should use a remove the `<button>`.

Answer (score 0):

```
a:hover {
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

please add this css to your code